# java: save the images in folder

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans

I have capturing images from webcam and storing them in a folder. The path of folder and name of image is provided i.e. hard coded into code. Now I don't want to hard code the name of image, I want to create it dynamically. I am giving the path as

```
 String string_ip="F:\\gatepass\\Gatepass\\Images\\rose.jpg";
```

Here I want to create name rose.jpg as dynamically, and also I want to give name as user name (user name is fetched from database)
But I am unable to do that, Please help me.

Comment: What is it that you're unable to do? Fetch the username from the database? Add the username to the file name string?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
String base_url="F:\\gatepass\\Gatepass\\Images\\{0}.jpg";

String username_from_DB = "rose"

String string_ip = MessageFormat.format(base_url,username_from_DB);
```

Then save image at string_ip, same as before you are saving.